# Kubernetes Load Balancer Type not responding to External IP Address

Tags: kubernetes

I've been trying to use the below to expose my application to a public IP. This is being done on Azure. The public IP is generated but when I browse to it I get nothing.

This is a Django app which runs the container on Port 8000. The service runs at Port 80 at the moment but even if I configure the service to run at port 8000 it still doesn't work.

Is there something wrong with the way my service is defined?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web
  labels:
    app: hmweb
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
  selector:
    app: hmweb
    tier: frontend
  type: LoadBalancer

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hmweb-deployment
  labels:
    app: hmweb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hmweb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hmweb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hmweb
        image: nw_webimage
        envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: new-config
        command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
        args: ["gunicorn saleor.wsgi -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:8000"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: key
```

Output of kubectl describe service web (name of service:)

```
Name:                     web
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=hmweb
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"hmweb"},"name":"web","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"ports":[{"port":...
Selector:                 app=hmweb
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.0.86.131
LoadBalancer Ingress:     13.69.127.16
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               8000/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31827/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.0.112:8000
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:
  Type    Reason                Age   From                Message
  ----    ------                ----  ----                -------
  Normal  EnsuringLoadBalancer  8m    service-controller  Ensuring load balancer
  Normal  EnsuredLoadBalancer   7m    service-controller  Ensured load balancer
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason behind that is your service has two selector `app: hmweb` and `tier: frontend` and your deployment pods has only single label named `app: hmweb`. Hence when your service is created it could not find the pods which has both the labels and doesn't connect to any pods. Also, if you have container running on `8000` port then you must define `targetPort` which has the value of container port on which container is running, else it will take both `targetPort` and `port` value as same you defined in your service i.e. `port: 80`

The correct yaml for your deployment is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web
  labels:
    app: hmweb
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8000
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: hmweb
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've changed this to what you've said (makes sense), but the result is the same. Web page doesn't load

Comment: could you please share output of `kubectl describe svc <svc_name>`

Comment: The service looks ok, you must be able to access your app using `13.69.127.16` , you are using the external IP to access app right?

Comment: Yes using the external IP, but not working. I've even checked Azure and the FW rule is allowed on the NSG

Comment: Try to curl following `10.244.0.112:8000` and see if your app endpoints working fine. If it works fine then we have to debug where is the issue in service

Comment: can I run curl using kubectl?

Comment: No, you can do it if you have `curl` utility on your VM.

Comment: The application is fine, even checked the kubectl logs for the app and it showing that Gunicorn is running on port 8000

Comment: Have you been able to solve this? I seem to be having the same issue... Thanks

Comment: Having the same problem, app runs fine but the external ip of the service (load balancer) doesn't respond